# Getting error when try to retrieve the image for a azure container app with terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-container-apps

I am writing a terraform code and getting "Can't access attributes on a list of objects." error when try to retrieve the image of container.

Below is the code

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.76.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {
    
  }
}

data "azurerm_container_app" "aca" {
  name                = "containername"
  resource_group_name = "resourcegroupname"
}

output "return_value" {
    value = data.azurerm_container_app.aca.template.container[0].image
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Please provide what exactly is the value of `data.azurerm_container_app.aca`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form the error message I'm guessing `template` is a list itself, thus you should do something like:

```
output "return_value" {
    value = data.azurerm_container_app.aca.template[0].container[0].image
}
```